# Why is $\frac{e^{i\pi n/50} + 1}{e^{i\pi n/50}-1} = \frac{e^{i\pi n/100} + e^{-i\pi n/100}}{e^{i\pi n/100} - e^{i\pi n/100}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Can someone explain why this is the case? I am trying to use this in one of my proofs.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Now the RHS has 0 in the denominator.

Comment: @Math-fun I know. My comment is for the current edit. The terms in the denominator of the RHS cancel each other out and there's now a division by 0. I am sure this is a typo.

Comment: I will wait till the question is settled and will come back again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Start from 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{ \frac{1}{e^{i\pi n/100}} (e^{i\pi n/50}+1) }{\frac{1}{e^{i\pi n/100}}(e^{i\pi n/50}-1)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=e^{i\theta} $ and   $\theta =\frac{nπ}{100}$
$$\therefore LHS=\frac{Cos(2\theta)+1+iSin(2\theta)}{Cos(2\theta)+iSin(2\theta)-1}$$
$$=\frac{2Cos^2\theta +2iSin\theta Cos\theta}{-2Sin^2\theta +2iSin\theta Cos\theta}$$
$$=\frac{2Cos\theta (Cos\theta +iSin\theta )}{2iSin\theta (Cos\theta +iSin\theta)}$$
$$=\frac{2Cos\theta }{2iSin\theta }$$
$$=\frac {2Re(z)}{2iIm(z)}$$
$$=\frac{z+\bar z}{z- \bar z}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let 
$$\begin{align}A = \exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) &= \exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) + \frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right)} \\ &= \frac{\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right)\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) + 1}{\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right)} \\ &= \frac{\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100} + \frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) + 1}{\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right)} = \,?\end{align}$$

Similarly, let $$B = \exp\left(\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) - \exp\left(-\frac{i\pi n}{100}\right) = \,?$$
What do you get for $\dfrac AB$?

Comment: This answer assumes that there is a typing error in the denominator of the RHS of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$, $$\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}\cdot 1 =\frac{x+1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{x^{-1/2}}{x^{-1/2}}=\frac {x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}$$ So now let $x=e^{i\pi n/50}$.

Incidentally,  $e^{i\pi n/50}=(-1)^{n/50}$ $\stackrel {\small\rm or}{=} i^{n/25}$ by Euler's identity.